# In Cocoa, how could you create an NSImage from a view? (Very similar to Top Sites in Safari 4.)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics

Actually, almost exactly the same thing. A matrix of small views that would expand out when you click on them. I don't know if it makes more sense to take a snapshot of the view as an image and work with that, or if there is a way to keep the views "live". Thoughts on either approach are welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[view dataWithPDFInsideRect:[view bounds]]];
```

Comment: Don't forget to release the image (sooner or later) if you're not running under GC.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [view bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[view bounds]];
[view cacheDisplayInRect:[view bounds] toBitmapImageRep:bitmap];
```

Then use that to draw elsewhere, perhaps by placing it into an NSImage. Or alternatively, use the PDF-based technique described by @Chuck.

Comment: Do you know if there’s a substantial difference in creating a bitmap representation compared to a PDF representation, Mike? A bitmap representation is somehow always transparent in my case, but the PDF representation captures the same portion of the view (and strangely works where taking the bitmap representation fails).

Comment: To my knowledge they both go through the same machinery, of drawing the view hierarchy into a graphics context. The difference then would be what sort of context is used. There may be more to it though